# Why does my Node.js API Gateway hang indefinitely when making a POST request with a body using Axios, while it works fine without a body?

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, api-gateway

I'm currently working on a Node.js API gateway project and have implemented the following fundamental features:

- When a user initiates a request to the gateway, the gateway identifies the appropriate microservice to forward the request.
- Subsequently, it utilizes Axios to make a call to the specific microservice server, including the required credentials, headers, and, if applicable, the request body.
- The microservice processes the request and sends the response back to the gateway, which, in turn, forwards the response to the user.

I'm currently facing an issue with my API gateway. When I send a `POST` request `without a body`, the request is processed `successfully`. However, when I `include a body` in the Axios request, it causes the request to `hang and run indefinitely`.

I've identified a few key observations during my troubleshooting process to pinpoint the issue:

1. The URLs and ports are correct
2. Request goes through the gateway properly
3. The microservice server receives the request

Terminal outputs:

1. Gateway

   ```bash
   Server started on port 8080
   [nodemon] files triggering change check: registryFiles\registry.json
   [nodemon] changes after filters (before/after): 1/0
   POST /gateway/register 200 22.588 ms - 34
   http://localhost:8081/hi
   POST /gateway/fakeapi/hi 500 1058.922 ms - 51
   ```
2. Microservice

   ```bash
   Registered successfully
   Server started on port 8081
   POST /hi - - ms - -
   ```

These are the essential files:

1. Gateway

   1. app.js

      ```js
      require("dotenv").config();
      require("express-async-errors");

      const express = require("express");
      const morgan = require("morgan");

      const { pageNotFound } = require("./middlewares/page-not-found");
      const { errorHandlerMiddleware } = require("./middlewares/error-handler");

      const app = express();

      app.use(morgan("dev"));

      app.use(express.json());

      const { router } = require("./routes");

      app.get("/", (req, res) => {
          res.send("Hello World!");
      });

      app.use("/gateway", router);

      app.use(pageNotFound);
      app.use(errorHandlerMiddleware);

      const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

      app.listen(port, () => {
          console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`); // eslint-disable-line
      });
      ```
   2. routes.js

      ```js
      const express = require("express");

      const router = express.Router();

      const { c1, register } = require("../controllers");

      router.all("/:apiName/:path(*)", c1);

      router.post("/register", register);

      module.exports = { router };
      ```
   3. controller (c1.js)

      ```js
      const { StatusCodes } = require("http-status-codes");
      const registry = require("../registryFiles/registry.json");
      const axios = require("axios");

      const { NotFoundError } = require("../errors");

      module.exports.c1 = async (req, res) => {
          const baseUrl = registry.services[req.params.apiName]?.baseUrl;

          if (!baseUrl) {
              throw new NotFoundError(
                  `API ${req.params.apiName} not found in registry`
              );
          }

          console.log(baseUrl + req.params.path);
          const response = await axios({
              method: req.method,
              url: baseUrl + req.params.path,
              headers: {
                  "Content-Type": "application/json",
                  ...req.headers,
              },
              data: req.body,
              timeout: 1000,
          });

          res.status(StatusCodes.OK).json({
              msg: "done dude!",
              status: true,
              result: response.data,
          });
      };
      ```
2. Microservice

   1. app.js

      ```js
      require("dotenv").config();
      require("express-async-errors");

      const express = require("express");
      const morgan = require("morgan");

      const { pageNotFound } = require("./middlewares/page-not-found");
      const { errorHandlerMiddleware } = require("./middlewares/error-handler");

      const { registerApiToGateWay } = require("./utils/register-api-in-gateway");

      const app = express();

      app.use(morgan("dev"));

      app.use(express.json({ limit: "50mb" }));

      const { router } = require("./routes");

      app.use("/", router);

      app.use(pageNotFound);
      app.use(errorHandlerMiddleware);

      const port = process.env.PORT || 8081;

      const startServer = async () => {
          try {
              await registerApiToGateWay();

              app.listen(port, () => {
                  console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`); // eslint-disable-line
              });
          } catch (error) {
              console.log(error);
          }
      };

      startServer();
      ```
   2. routes.js

      ```js
      const express = require("express");

      const router = express.Router();

      const { c1, c2 } = require("../controllers");

      router.post("/hi", c2);

      router.get("/hello/hi", c1);

      module.exports = { router };
      ```
   3. controllers (c2.js)

      ```js
      const { StatusCodes } = require("http-status-codes");

      module.exports.c2 = async (req, res) => {
          res.status(StatusCodes.OK).json({ result: "Hello World!" });
      };
      ```

I've been trying to troubleshoot this issue, and despite searching online, I haven't been able to find a solution. I'm unsure about what might be causing the problem.